# How to take input file, reverse word order, write to output file in C++

Tags: c++, reverse, fstream

> Take the contents of an input text file and write them in reverse order of words to an output file.  Your program can ignore line breaks.  You will need to use arrays.

(unnecessary crap removed)  Aaaaah, panic, please help!

EDIT:  What I have so far.  Still lost on how to reverse word order now.

```
//Kristen Korz
//CIS 22A
//This program reads an input file and writes the words in reverse order to an output file.

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //create and link input...
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("input.txt");
    //...and output files
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("output.txt");

    //error message for file open fail
    if (inputFile.fail())
        cout << "Error opening the file.\n";

    //constant for max size
    const int MAXSIZE = 1024;
    //string array and temporary-use string
    string words[MAXSIZE];
    string str;
    //read words from input file
    for (int i = 0; (inputFile >> str) && (i < MAXSIZE); ++i)
    {
        words[i] = str;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    
    //for showing if read correctly
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; ++i)
        cout << words[i] << endl;





    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

What I've got successfully reads the input file word for word.  I can figure out everything except how to reverse the word order for then writing to output.txt
This is our first program reversing the order of things, yes.

### EDIT 2:

Okay, so the best I can guess is this:

```
    //constant for max size
    const int MAXSIZE = 1024;
    //string array and temporary-use string
    string words[MAXSIZE];
    string str;                 //note: variables will be used for output loops too

    //read words from input file
    for (int i = 0; (inputFile >> str) && (i < MAXSIZE); ++i)
    {
        words[i] = str;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    
    //for showing if read correctly
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; ++i)
        cout << words[i] << endl;

    //for writing in reverse word order to output file
    for (int i = MAXSIZE-1; (outputFile << str) && (i >= 0); --i)
    {
        words[i] = str;
    }
    outputFile.close();

    //for showing if written correctly
    for (int i= MAXSIZE-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }
```

The input section works fine.  Output just repeats last word of input for each iteration.

### EDIT 3:

Just kidding, everything except actual writing of output file works.  Output in the terminal is corrects by getting rid of the "-1" after `MAXSIZE` in the initialization.  Adjusting the code that writes the file in a similar way does not solve the repeating "works." (final word of input file) written to output.txt

### EDIT 4:

Relevant code is now:

```
    //constant for max size
    const int MAXSIZE = 1024;
    //string array and temporary-use string
    string words[MAXSIZE];
    string str;                 //note: variables will be used for output loops too

    //read words from input file
    for (int i = 0; (inputFile >> str) && (i < MAXSIZE); ++i)
    {
        words[i] = str;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    
    //for showing if read correctly
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; ++i)
        cout << words[i] << " ";

    //for writing in reverse word order to output file
    for (int i = MAXSIZE; (outputFile << str) && (i >= 0); --i)
    {
        words[i] = str;
    }
    outputFile.close();

    //for showing if written correctly
    for (int i = MAXSIZE; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        cout << words[i] << " ";
    }
```

If I change `i>=0` to `i=0` (which I mistakenly typed first try) in `for (int i = MAXSIZE; (outputFile << str) && (i >= 0); --i)`, then `cout` in terminal is perfect.  Can't figure out how to get output file to not be repeated "works." Why is it doing that?  Note: output to terminal optional, so I don't really care why that wants `i` assigned to 0 in previous for loop in terms of being able to finish the assignment

Comment: Have you tried any code till now for reading or reversing word or writing file?

Comment: Try breaking the problem down into steps.  Can you read a list of words from `cin`?  If so, then you should be able to adapt that to read a list of words from a file using ifstream.  Next, can you store those words rather than just throwing them away after reading them?

Comment: Wait, I have an idea...

Comment: You should only need to change one line now:  `for (int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; ++i)`.  How would you make that iterate over your array in the opposite order?

Comment: Nevermind, I got all the words to my output file, but the order makes no sense to me, neither forward or backward.  Just weird.  o.O

Comment: What's in your input file, and what are you getting out of your program?

Comment: This line is wrong: `int i= MAXSIZE-1`  Perhaps you should remember how many words you actually read, so you don't start printing unused parts of the array.

Comment: input file contents "This is my test file. I hope this works."

Comment: output file contents is just "works." repeated

Comment: Duh.  Thanks Ben Voigt, works now.  Thanks nix so very much!

Comment: Use a std::vector ...

Comment: the other @Ben: They probably haven't learned that yet.

Comment: the more experienced but *maybe* not as beautiful @BenVoigt :p no time like the present!

Comment: @KristenKorz: Now you get to answer your own question... (do that after the assignment is due so your classmates can't just copy your code).  Also, next time you need help, make the first attempt before asking.  And stuff related to your university (due date, how to submit) we don't need.  It's enough to say "I'm working on an assignment, the requirements are (this).  I tried (that, including code), and I'm stuck (here).  How can I make it (what it should do) instead of (what it does now)?"

Comment: +1 for figuring it out without someone giving you a complete answer.

Comment: We haven't gone over using a vector and can't use anything not covered in class.  Which was why I couldn't find any help from pre-existing questions - they all used a vector!  Any idea why my changes to the for loop arguments would print what I'm aiming for to the screen, but not the file

Comment: Why are you using completely different loops for printing to the file vs. printing to the console?

Comment: Good question.  Just thought of the tasks separately so I wrote it as two loops, but yeah, not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Another algorithm:

1. Map the file into memory or read it into `std::vector<char>` or `std::string`.
2. Reverse each word individually with `std::reverse`.
3. Reverse the entire file with `std::reverse`.
4. Write the file back if it was read into a container.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
//Kristen Korz
//CIS 22A
//This program reads an input file and writes the words in reverse order to an output file.

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //create and link input...
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("input.txt");
    //...and output files
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("output.txt");

    //error message for file open fail
    if (inputFile.fail())
        cout << "Error opening the file.\n";

    //constant for max size
    const int MAXSIZE = 1024;
    //string array and temporary-use string
    string words[MAXSIZE];
    string str;                 //note: variables will be used for output loops too

    //read words from input file
    for (int i = 0; (inputFile >> str) && (i < MAXSIZE); ++i)
    {
        words[i] = str;
        //for showing in terminal if read correctly
        cout << words[i] << " " << i << " ";
    }
    inputFile.close();
    cout << endl;

    //something wrong with for loop resulting in i apparently not updating
    for (int i = MAXSIZE - 1; (outputFile << str) && (i >= 0); --i)
    {
        if (str.size() < MAXSIZE)
        {
            //for showing in terminal if written correctly
            cout << words[i] << " " << i << " ";
        }
    }
    outputFile.close();
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So, let me try to help you the best way I can.
Maybe, it will be helpful.
Take the contents of an input text file and write them in reverse order of words to an output file. Your program can ignore line breaks. You will need to use arrays.

```
inputFile.open (" input.txt ");
outputFile.open (" output.txt ");

if (inputFile.fail()) {
    cout << "input.txt not found" << endl;

    return -1;
}
if (outputFile.fail()) {
    cout << "not able to open output.txt" << endl;
    return -1;

}

int i = 0;
int count = 0;
string words[1000];
while (inputFile >> words[i]) {
    count++;
    i++;
}

for (int j = count; j >= 0; j--) {
    outputFile << words[j] << " ";
}


inputFile.close();
outputFile.close();

return 0; }
```