# c++ for loop with decrement update causing infinite loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, infinite-loop, decrement

This is part of a greater code for reading an input file word-for-word, then printing the words in reverse order.  It uses a string array called words[] to store, word-by-word, the char strings from an input file earlier in the program:

```
//print to screen
for (int i = MAXSIZE; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << words[i] << " ";
    }
```

Test input file contents:

```
This is my test file. I hope this works.
```

Output is just "works. " repeating on and on.
Why is the i-- apparently never happening?

EDIT:  Everything from my code.  I'm on a bit of a time crunch here, to say the least.  MAXSIZE=1024 part of lab prompt.  Can't use vectors or reverse; seen that all over, but it's off limits for this lab.  New to programming, so if you could refrain from being condescending, that'd be great.  Just trying to get this to work.  The reading input.txt and print to screen bit works fine.  Output portion is utter fail and I don't know why.  Can someone just tell me why instead of insulting me, thanks?

```
//Kristen Korz
//CIS 22A
//This program reads an input file and writes the words in reverse order to an output file.

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //create and link input...
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("input.txt");
    //...and output files
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("output.txt");

    //error message for file open fail
    if (inputFile.fail())
        cout << "Error opening the file.\n";

    //constant for max size
    const int MAXSIZE = 1024;
    //string array and temporary-use string
    string words[MAXSIZE];
    string str;                 //note: variables will be used for output loops too

    //read words from input file
    for (int i = 0; (inputFile >> str) && (i < MAXSIZE); ++i)
    {
        words[i] = str;
        //for showing in terminal if read correctly
        cout << words[i] << " ";
    }
    inputFile.close();
    cout << endl;

    //something wrong with for loop resulting in i apparently not updating
    for (int i = MAXSIZE; (outputFile << str) && (i >= 0); --i)
    {
        words[i] = str;
        //for showing in terminal if written correctly
        cout << words[i] << " ";
    }
    outputFile.close();
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

For output with i also printed, my cout statements in the for-loops say:

```
cout << words[i] << " " << i << " ";
```

Giving terminal output:
This 0 is 1 my 2 test 3 file. 4 I 5 hope 6 this 7 works. 8 
works. 1023 works. 1022 works. 1021 (lots of repeats of works. followed by decrementing numbers) works. 3 works. 2 works. 1 works. 0

Comment: What is `words`? How is `words` declared? And how do you get the "input file" into `words`?

Comment: [Related question **here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007955/how-to-take-input-file-reverse-word-order-write-to-output-file-in-c)

Comment: According to the thread linked by @WhozCraig it looks like you're filling your entire `words` array with the last word of the input, which is "works".

Comment: @user657267 that is *exactly* what that loop does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output loop does:

```
words[i] = str;
```

for every iteration. `str` still holds the value of the last string you input, so this sets every member of `words` to be the same string.  Since your last input string was `"works"`, this explains why you output `"works"` every time.

It should work better if you just remove that line. Also, start from `MAXSIZE - 1`.  The valid indices of the array are `0` through `MAXSIZE-1`. Your out-of-bounds access causes undefined behaviour, although apparently in this instance it had no effect.

However if your input only has 8 words as you suggest, then outputting 1024 words will give you a lot of blank space. Consider starting the output from where `i` got up to, instead of `MAXSIZE - 1`.

Comment: And there is the obvious answer right in front of my eyeballs the whole time!  I knew once I saw what the problem was, I'd feel like an idiot for not getting it.  Thank you for bringing my confusion and frustration to the end I should have been able to reach myself.

Comment: To be fair, David Young's answer actually says the exact same thing as mine, if you read it carefully :) (I didn't read carefully enough at first either else I wouldn't have posted)

Answer (score 0):

Viewing WhozCraig's link, if you have:

```
const int MAXSIZE = 1024;
string words[MAXSIZE];

for (int i = MAXSIZE; i >= 0; i--) {
    cout << words[i] << " ";
}
```

You have a string that from 0..1023.

Accessing words[1024] is potentially dangerous.

For iterate correctly your string do:

```
for (int i = MAXSIZE - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    cout << words[i] << " ";
}
```

By the way, when you fill words, add a control:

```
for (int i = 0; (inputFile >> str) && (i < MAXSIZE); ++i)) {
    if(str.size() <= MAXSIZE) {
       words[i] = str;
    }
}
```

## update

Be sure that your string in file:

```
"This is my test file. I hope this works. "
```

doesn't end with a space. To be sure, test adding "EOF" to your string:

```
"This is my test file. I hope this works.EOF"
```

Other, do your loop in this way:

```
int i = 0;
while(inputFile.good() && i < MAXSIZE) {
  std::string word << inputFile;
  if(!word.empty())
    words[i] = str;
    //for showing in terminal if read correctly
    cout << words[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Nothing potential about it. Its pure *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Maybe you're unlucky and words[1024] is the position where 'i' stored. Print 'i' too for couriosity

Comment: Printing i following each words[i] gives This 0 is 1 my 2 test 3 file. 4 I 5 hope 6 this 7 works. 8 
works. 1023 works. 1022 works. (until works. 0)

Comment: ?? I can't understand.. update your post with "cout << i" output

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  I was slow connecting the dots, and I know how frustrating that can be.

Comment: Re the update: what's the issue if the file ends with a space?  He's inputting with `>>` to a string, which skips white space.

Answer (score 0):

At the part marked as not working (the second `for` loop), `str` is being read from but it is never changed to anything else in that loop, so it repeats the last word. `i` is being updated, the problem is that `str` is not being updated.

The other issue is that you are trying to access an element past the end of the array, as WhozCraig and Velthune discussed in their answers. You need to properly figure out what you want to do with `words` in your second `for` loop. This is key. Also, you need to store where the array you read in ends.

Comment: Okay, I can see that and I feel like I should have enough at this point to put it all together, but I still don't understand what I need to do to fix it.

Comment: @KristenKorz Consider this: What is contained in the `words` array when the second `for` loop is run? What should be done with the information in that array?

Comment: @KristenKorz I added a couple more hints.

Comment: the last iteration the first for-loop does is assign `words[1023]' the memory location str...  which is where the second for-loop is getting the data to write to the output file from.  I still don't know what I'm supposed to do to get this darn thing to work.  I get why what I have doesn't work, but not what the solution is supposed to be.

Comment: so I get the going past the end of the array problem.

Comment: but the way this was originally set up, str was just a placeholder, really.  which doesn't work for when I need to then write the output file.  and that's as far as my brain's getting and I know the answer is right in front of my face.

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience and guidance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem why you get a lot of "works" here is:

After this piece of codes:

```
//read words from input file
for (int i = 0; (inputFile >> str) && (i < MAXSIZE); ++i)
{
    words[i] = str;
    //for showing in terminal if read correctly
    cout << words[i] << " ";
}
inputFile.close();
cout << endl;

//str = "works";
```

The values of variable `str` is `works`.

After that, you set every elements in `words` by `str`. So every elements in the `words` now are the same value `works`.

```
 for (int i = MAXSIZE; (outputFile << str) && (i >= 0); --i)
{
    words[i] = str;//=="works"
    //for showing in terminal if written correctly
    cout << words[i] << " ";
}
outputFile.close();
cout << endl;
```